# Why does the program throw an exception after executing the "npm install" command?

Tags: node.js, laravel, processmaker

I'm trying to install ProcessMaker 4.2.30 Community Edition following the steps that can be found on this GitHub: https://github.com/ProcessMaker/processmaker

However, I got stuck on an error after running the npm install command. The thrown error is the following:

> ErrorException : mkdir(): File exists at
> /home/vagrant/processmaker/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:492

For some reason, the command can't be executed, because it detects that the file already exists inside the project, but after checking its contents, said file can't be found inside it. I've tried deleting the project and reinstalling, but it didn't work.

Comment: You might want to try this out.. might be a little easier than doing it from scratch https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/processmaker/processmaker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `/storage/api-docs` folder and try again.
This works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change root directory or manual delete this file.
If that doesn't help, try doing it from admin names